# Publish Docker containers via Avahi(-register-service)?

Tags: router, dns, docker, avahi

I am getting an OpenWRT router soon (FriendlyElec R6S) and while planning what to run on it, I was wondering if it was possible to publish my Jellyfin container by using Avahi?

My main goal is to use either `jellyfin.local` or potentially a configured local DNS server to resolve `jellyfin.my.domain` to the router, to a reverse proxy that then forwards to docker. The latter is possible bot kinda convoluted, so I wondered if there was a way I could achieve this by just using the already existing Avahi?

I know I can't do that from within the Docker container itself, as Avahi needs udp/5353, which the host already uses, and the connected virtual network is system local - thus, the IPs there are useless to the other peers on the network.

Any good way I can automate this? Thanks!